# TensorFlow environment Setup in Windows 10 with Nvidia GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I want to implement [this](http://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-with-deep-learning-in-python-with-keras) example. And thus I need to install python along with some libraries including *Scikit-Learn, Numpy, Scipy, matplotlib.pyplot, Pandas, Keras, TensorFlow* on my Windows 10 machine.

Currently, I can not use my GPU with TensorFlow. I tried installing CUDA. But still having difficulties setting path variables for python. I also tried installing Tensorflow with Anaconda. But that didn't help.

May I get a suggestion on installing python and its machine-learning packages on Windows with Nvidia GPU support in a fashion that doesn't have dependency issues?

Answer (score 2):

Install python 3.6. Then use pip to install those packages. pip should be bundled with your Python install.

Anaconda has caused me many issues on windows personally. Try to avoid it if possible in my opinion.

Comment: But keras doesn't have support for Python 3.6

Comment: the newest version of tensorflow is only support python 3.5.x on windows

Comment: OK, 3.5 will still include pip. What exactly are you having trouble with? Do you need to add python to PATH or are you having troubles with modules alone?

Comment: I can't install keras and SciPy. Keras installation request returns me this- https://pastebin.com/wCvgvjzG

Answer (score 0):

I also install tensorflow recently, I find it's very smoothly. As you have installed vs2015, you can then install cuda. When you install the latest cuda, it will config the environment path and config for vs2015 automatically. After this, install python3.5, then use pip install tensorflow. Then you  can run the tesorflow demo, when you encounter path issue, you just add it to the path, I remeber there are very file path issue. And when you use python, sometime you'll encounter module not find. Then just install these modules with pip.

Comment: It helped me. But I still can't install SciPy and Keras.

Comment: This is the error I am getting pastebin.com/wCvgvjzG